# Bool value not retuning false in palindrome function, C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I've sadly read every post pertaining to this topic and can't seem to solve my issue. It's driving me mad.

For some reason on my second or third iteration, if (beg != end) won't return false. It returns false properly if I input, for instance, "bool", but not "blob."

I printed beg and end to make sure things are flowing properly, but still can't find where things are going wrong.

Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool palindrome_check (string str)
{
    string return_str;
    int length = str.length()-1;
    string beg = str.substr(0, 1);
    string end = str.substr(length, 1);

    if (beg != end)
    {
      //  cout << beg << " " << end << endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if ((str.length() > 2) && (str.length() != 0))
    {
        string new_str = str.substr(1, length - 1);
      //  cout << new_str << endl;
        palindrome_check(new_str);
    }
        return true;
}
int main ()
{

    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> input;

    bool is_palindrome = palindrome_check (input);

    cout << is_palindrome << endl;
}
```

Comment: Perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line and inspect variable values along the way.

Comment: When you input "blob" the first character is equal to the last character, and so in this case `begin` and `end` are equal. By the way it's generally a good idea to not use these names (`begin` and `end`) for anything other than the standard `begin` and `end` functions.

Comment: `(str.length() > 2) && (str.length() != 0)` - redundant...

Comment: You never use the result of your recursive `palindrome_check` call. You simply ignore it. What is the point of calling it then?

Comment: A much simpler way to write `palindrome_check` would be `bool palindrome_check(const std::string& str) { std::string reverse_str(str.crbegin(), str.crend()); return str == reverse_str; }`

Comment: @Jesper Juhl easiest, but less effective for long string,  because it creates full copy of string. but who said that we cannot use normal and reverse iterator to iterate string within single loop...

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the return values of recursive calls:

```
        string new_str = str.substr(1, length - 1);
        return palindrome_check(new_str);
    }
    return true;
```

And you should have checked the length of the input string *before* you extract the first and the last character from it.

If you fix the two mistakes, it should be alright then.